# idempotent email sending or send once

Tags: c#, hangfire, asp.net-core-6.0, idempotent

I am using Hangfire to run a scheduled job (every Friday) which gathers information and sends an email to each member (of our system) who requested it.

The Hangfire setup and job are all working OK - except for if the system (server, IIS, website, code, etc?) fails and requires the website to be restarted while the Hangfire job is being processed, which then causes the job to be retried.

The issue is dealing with the fact that some member emails may have already been sent, so should not be sent again, for this job run. Also, it may be that we need to manually restart the Hangfire job to complete the email send, but again not to resend emails already sent during this job run.

I realise that failures could happen during / within the actual Email sending system, but for now, I am happy to take the return from the Email function as "proof" of an email send:

```
foreach (var member in memberList)
{
    // if email has already been sent for this member then skip to the next member
    ??

    // Do necessary processing to get data and format email content

    // Send the email to the member
    bool emailSent = _emailService.SendEmail(member, emailDetails);

    if (emailSent){
        // Record that the email has been sent for member for this job run
        ??
    }
}
```

So, what I'm trying to figure out is how to record that an email has been sent, according to "SendEmail", for a member for the current run of the job.

The record of emails sent would need to be cleared, or a new list created, the next time the job starts from scratch, rather than being a restarted job.

I appreciate this is a little vague or generalistic, but I am mainly looking for ideas on how to manage this not necessarily a complete code solution.

Comment: There are _many_ ways to do this. Are you having any specific problems?

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay sorry, maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. This is not something I've done before so am looking for help on how to do it, whether that be a general description of the process or a pointer to a similar example. I thought of writing successful sends to a DB table but how do I know if my code is starting fresh or reentering for whatever reason?

Comment: You have to store this list of already sent users somewhere (after each individual user call) and take it into account when you iterate over your member list again. Cause this thing is Job depending, your storage should use the job id somewhere within the key under which this list is stored (can be accessed via PerformContext method parameter). Either use some already existing external storage like redis cache or sql database or store it as Hangfire Job Parameter. But be aware that a job parameter has a maximum length, depending on the underlying storage used.

Comment: @Oliver ah, thank you - I wasn't aware of "PerformContext". So that will help with the job being rerun by Hangfire. Just need to consider what to do if it gets manually (re)run ... maybe that should be a known issue (that duplicate emails may happen)

Comment: If you have stored the already sent users for this job somewhere and retrieve this list at start of the job, it doesn't matter, how the job gets restarted (manually or automatically) as long it is *the same job* (aka same job id). If you need to store this information job independent, you could instead add a timestamp, when a specific user received a mail, but then an external storage like redis or sql is needed and job parameter can't be used.

Comment: I am not sure a boolean sent/not sent for each user and jobid is the best solution for your problem.
I guess you have to store a list of tuples with userId and datetime of the last sent email for this userid. When performing your job, if the date is more than one week old or null, send the mail and update/insert the tuple, otherwise do nothing and continue with next userId. I guess you don't even need the job name for this, unless you have several similar jobs.