How can I "discard" new task for being queue if a command is already processing?
I've Hangfire setup on a Windows Service, which I start basically with _server = new BackgroundJobServer();
I've somethings like 30 commands configured, each with different Command/Parameters (which is a basic setup I believe).
Each task must be continuously executed every 1 Minute. So I've setup columns Cron and Frequency respectively as */1 * * * * and Every 1 minutes.
The problem is this: if I queue the 30 commands, and some of them takes more than 1 minute (i.e. 10 minutes due to heavy process to be executed), it continuously queue every task (also the ones which is already processing), resulting in a blocking/infinitely queue for the task which can't de-queue in 1 minute.
Example of method (i.e. Command) I have:
public void CMS1Integration(string systemCode)
public void CMS2Integration(string systemCode)
public void CMS3Integration(string systemCode)

This way, method CMS1Integration can run in parallel, but a single one for each systemCode I pass. So CMS1Integration("cms1Name1") + CMS1Integration("cms1Name2") can run in parallel, but not CMS1Integration("cms1Name1") + CMS1Integration("cms1Name1") (because it have the same systemCode).
How can I resolve it avoid the re-queue of already processing task?
Note: they are queued as recurring-jobs:
...
RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(hangFireCmd.Name, GetAction(hangFireCmd), hangFireCmd.Cron, TimeZoneInfo.Local);
...

Looking in the Set table, I find than this list (as example):
Id  Key Score   Value   ExpireAt
24279   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms1Name1   NULL
24280   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms1Name2   NULL
24281   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms1Name3   NULL
24282   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms2Name1   NULL
24283   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms2Name2   NULL
24284   recurring-jobs  1717711800  cms3Name1   NULL
24285   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms3Name2   NULL
24286   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms3Name3   NULL
24287   recurring-jobs  1717657740  cms3Name4   NULL


Have you checked out the suggestions in this SO post?

@AstridE. not really sure: it must run a single task for the pair method/command, not only method. The method I have are 5 for example, each of them with 6 different command.

Does this help? https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/recurring-jobs-dont-queue-when-already-in-queue/1969/8

@rand'Chris no it doesn't.

This may be a far-fetched suggestion, but have you considered alternatives to Hangfire? For instance Coravel? I haven't tried it myself, but some colleagues mentioned it. It provides a PreventOverlapping method, to name-drop a possibly interesting feature.

@AstridE. Refactor would be huge at this time...

Why you upvoted no answer? No answerers gave you help at all?

@Electrionics not really. If I need to implement my own queue, that's could introduce lots af artefacts (thread, sync, deadlock, and so on). The reason I use Hangfire is not to reinvent the wheel. I hope it got its own mechanism to "trigger" somethings if the same "command/method" is not processing (which Statuses are managed by Hangfire itself).

Solutions, proposed by users, was helpful, though? If you found your own solution - you can post your  answer to help others in future. You started bounty, got highest attention to question, asked everybody several times in comments and decided to loose rep but not to gave it to anybody, just loose points. And even when you loose rep, you decided not to upvote anybody. I hope community users will look at this question before help you. Good luck.

@Electrionics I don't find any solution. Still an open topic. There is no hurry, I think I'll wait some other people, and do another bounty. Its the 3° right now. Do an answer doesn't mean get a valide solution, do you agree? P.s. I've upvote all answer.

There are a couple ways to solve this, depending on your setup, but probably the best way is to solve your throughput problem. Absent of making the individual jobs more efficient or more stable in execution time, you could:

Increase job throughput. You could add more parallelization to ensure jobs don't sit in the queue for greater than your requirements. To achieve this you can either increase the WorkerCount for your configuration of the Hangfire Server which enables more jobs to run in parallel on a single instance or you can add more instances of your server application. Of course your code and deployment scenario would need to support this.

Decrease total job queue by not executing everything every minute.

It is not my preferred method, but you could use the Hangfire monitoring Api in the beginning of your job methods to delete additional enqueued instances of the same job. There are a couple prerequisites to this. First, every job needs a unique identifier that you control. This means if you call the same method with different parameters then each of those method calls needs a unique Hangfire name. Second, you'll have to inject an instance of IBackgroundJobClient into your jobs so each job can manage the queue. Third, the method itself has to somehow be aware of the way in which it was called. You may want to include PerformContext as a method argument so the job knows a bit about itself. Finally, you can get a reference to the Hangfire monitoring api and delete duplicate jobs with something like this:


IMonitoringApi api = JobStorage.Current.GetMonitoringApi();
var enqueuedJobs = api.EnqueuedJobs("yourQueueName", 0, 50);

// The way you filter in the where clause is up to you here. You'll have access to invocation data for each job so you could filter on parameters supplied matching those of the current method running
foreach(var job in enqueuedJobs.Where(j => j.Value.Job.ToString() == jobName))
{
    _jobClient.Delete(job.Key);
}


None of them seems to be the solution. I don't want to limit the number of parallel jobs, but limit each one to a single running (i.e. for each command/parameter, a single running).

Have you looked into DisableConcurrentExecution? You could also look into this: https://gist.github.com/odinserj/a8332a3f486773baa009

But isn't DisableConcurrentExecution used for single method? Let say I've public void CMS1Integration(string systemCode), void CMS2Integration(string systemCode), void CMS3Integration(string systemCode), and so on. CMS1Integration can run in parallel, but shouldn't considering the systemCode (i.e. a single pair method/systemCode without parallelism). Is it more clear now? (I've also edited the question).

I've added further details on the question.

I see your update and it makes more sense now. In my answer I do mention that you could add logic to check the invocation parameters associated with various methods as well as the method names themselves. Hangfire gives you access to all of that via the monitoring API, you'll just have to write your own logic in a filter to manage the queue. I don't think there would be anything built in to Hangfire to do what you want.

Can you give a full example, using the info I give on the question about this "check"? If it works, you will get a nice bounty accept answer :)

No more helps? Any starting code I can start with?

You should always make your background Job reentrant. Suppose you have a list of tasks to execute. It's your responsability to track the execution status of the task. Every new schedule should take care about the tasks that are not executed yet.
Small example. Let say that you have a job that sends welcome email to newly registered user. You will have to track the status of this email in some persistent storage. Let say for simplicity that we have a column in our User table that holds the SendWelcomEmailStatus :
public enum SendWelcomEmailStatus
{
    ToDo = 0,
    Executing = 1,
    Done=2,
    Error=3
}

The first things to do in your job, is to read all Users with the status == SendWelcomEmailStatus.Todo (it's intentionally equal to 0 to be the default value when creating a new user), and then updating the value to SendWelcomEmailStatus.Executing. When the jobs ends you should update the value to Done or Error. You can have a separate job that handle errors value for retry.
This is your responsability, you should always design you execution to be reentrant as I said. Assume that multiple executions can occure on the same time.
Some Hangfire best practice : https://docs.hangfire.io/en/latest/best-practices.html
Sorry for my english, don't hesitate if you need more details, I can elaborate more. You can explain exactly what your job do every 1 minute so I can give you more enhancement ideas.

"It's your responsability to track the execution status of the task." Since Hangfire is made to manage this kind of tasks, I believe there are some methods I can use to achieve this...

No, Hangfire is responsible of managing the technical part of the tasks : schedules, queue, distribution of task to a pool...
It's not responsible of the reentrancy problems that you have to deal with in your task. Look at the best practice link that I sent you. Related question with the same answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72375768/idempotent-email-sending-or-send-once

You can create objects with the prevention of parallel calling actions.
Class MyCmd is an example solution.
public class MyCmd
{
    public readonly string Name;
    public readonly TimeSpan Timeout;
    public readonly Action Job;
    private bool isRunning;

    public MyCmd(string name, Action job, TimeSpan timeout)
    {
        Name = name;
        Timeout = timeout;
        Job = job;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        //skip it running now
        lock(this)
        {
            if(isRunning)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:T} Skip Run {Name}");
                return;
            }
            //skip next calls
            isRunning = true;
        }

        //run 
        Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:T} Start {Name} ");
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Job();
        }, cts.Token);

        if(Task.WaitAny(task, Task.Delay(Timeout)) == 0)
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:T} Stop {Name}");
        else
        {
            cts.Cancel();
            Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now:T} Timeout {Name}");
        }

        //allow next run
        lock(this)
            isRunning = false;
    }
}

Here is the demo app, showing usage of MyCmd.
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace SOW78554841
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static MyCmd[] cmds;
        private static Random rnd = new Random();
        internal static TimeSpan GetRandomTimeout() => TimeSpan.FromSeconds(.5 * rnd.Next(2, 12));

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //declare colection of jobs
            cmds = new[]
            {
                //use yourown action definitions insted Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout())
                new MyCmd("cms1Name1", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms1Name2", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms1Name3", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms2Name1", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms2Name2", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms3Name1", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms3Name2", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms3Name3", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
                new MyCmd("cms3Name4", () => Thread.Sleep(GetRandomTimeout()), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)),
            };

            //call RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate for cmds 
            
            //demo with timer
            using(Timer t = new Timer(TimerCallback, null, 0, 4000))
                Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Stop scheduler");
            Console.ReadLine();

        }

        private static void TimerCallback(Object o)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Scheduling");
            foreach(var cmd in cmds)
                Task.Run(cmd.Run);
        }
    }
}


If the method GetAction always returns the same delegate, then you can set it permanently (as delegate), in other way the lambda passed in the constructor will fire each time before a new job start. In the demo jobs always have new random execution time.

I don't have any of the code above. The only things I do is to call _server = new BackgroundJobServer(); on the Windows Service. This will create appropriate [HangFire].[Job] records on DB, somethings like {"Type":"HangFireCommon.HangfireCommonLibrary, HangFireCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","Method":"CMS1Integration","ParameterTypes":"[\"System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\"]","Arguments":null} as InvocationData, and the relative Argument for each call (i.e. the systemCode I pass to the backend method)

You have written the C# tag, and the code how you add jobs: RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(hangFireCmd.Name, GetAction(hangFireCmd), hangFireCmd.Cron, TimeZoneInfo.Local);. So, to use MyCmd you need declare it with action GetAction(hangFireCmd) and then use a cmd.Run as parameter of  RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate, that's all.

My answer will contain 2 points of view:

business
technical

BUSINESS:
Your approach to run commands every minute is not really good. If something processing 10 minutes, I can ask next questions to you: why you try to run it every minute? (you can separately configure cron for each command); is it ok with performance? (may be you can optimize it for batches, disable tracking of entities, optimize query by indexes etc.)
So the best is to clarify business needs of every command for now and for future and configure CRON schedules separately and optimize performance, if necessary for some business-critical commands. And design code the way, that counts future plans of business to each of these commands.
TECHNICAL
Technically, if you still need to run all every minute, or in general can't guarantee, that command will finish before next point will be reached by CRON schedule, you can use universal state, which determines if job in progress. I recommend to use most simple solution with wrapping data structure with access method:
private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, bool> commandsState;

private static void Initialize()
{
     if (commandsState == null)
     {
         commandsState = new ();
         commandsState.Add("Job1", false);
         commandsState.Add("Job2", false);
         // etc.
     }
}

private static bool SkipStart(string key)
{
     return commandsState[key];
}

private static void SetProgress(string key, bool progress = true)
{
     commandsState[key] = progress;
}

with command type identifier/name as key and bool value as progress. You actually can decide if to start one of commands depending on according value.
You have 30 commands, some of them may try to access the same resources. So if you schedule them to avoid any concurrency, test on actual data sets (in sense of data amounts), you can achieve non-intersection of commands and better performance.
For example: 3 commands take read-write access to table Users. You configure to run it every 5 minutes, 1-st, that takes <1 minute, on minutes *0/*5 (pseudo syntax), 2-nd, that takes <2 minutes, on minute *1/*6, and third, that takes <2 minutes, on minutes *3/*8. Other commands access other tables and must be scheduled separately. But for making such decisions you need performance testing or modelling, or at least some experiments. Don't forget that not only commands of background service access your tables (or other resources).
I recommend to do this analytical work. All described approaches can be helpful. Hope it make sense for you.

I don't have any of the code above. The only things I do is to call _server = new BackgroundJobServer(); on the Windows Service. This will create appropriate [HangFire].[Job] records on DB, somethings like {"Type":"HangFireCommon.HangfireCommonLibrary, HangFireCommon, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null","Method":"CMS1Integration","ParameterTypes":"[\"System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\"]","Arguments":null} as InvocationData, and the relative Argument for each call (i.e. the systemCode I pass to the backend method)

So, on the backend, I should intercept on each CMS1Integration/CMS2Integration/CMS3Integration etc method if some command with the passed systemCode is processing.

I could do somethings "handcrafted": do a query on [HangFire].[Job] table at every CMS1Integration/CMS2Integration/CMS3Integration etc calling, search SELECT * FROM [HangFire].[Job] where Arguments = '[""systemCode""]' and StateName != 'Succeeded', and if I got a records, delete the Job completely? Also if not elegant, how can this be accomplished?

Do you have access to changing Cron schedule? If so, I still propose you to set it the maximum convenient to real jobs performance and time they consume. I gave you algorithm how to do it. The code I've posted you should use the next way: if (!MyNewClass.SkipStart(job.Name)) { MyNewClass.SetProgress(job.Name); /* start job */ }   Also you need at some point (maybe inside this if) to call MyNewClass.SetProgress(job.Name, false); - depends on how and where you can check if job process finished.

You can call MyNewClass.SetProgress(job.Name, false); immediately after job finished. If you have multiple jobs, the key could be job.Name + hangFireCmd.Name for uniqueness reasons.

Cron schedule is ok: I need this frequency of update. I don't get your suggestion of call SetProgress: it can skip it, yes, but it will show on backlog of hangfire later that it has "processed" the job every time it get triggered (which is not true, and can deal of wrong logs). That's why I guess its better to work at Hangfire level and just doesn't queue the job at all. Or at least, a way to remove it instead of "skip" (not sure how efficient would be though)

Taking structure like concurrent dictionary (or even simple dictionary, if applicable) and skipping running - this is most lightweight solution in sense of memory and processor usage. And as you see - it also not depend on internal implementation of jobs and be easily modifiable, if necessary, than direct work with API, that you described.

Actually many things I said is about architecture and performance. Hope my advices make sense for you. Ask if something is unclear.
